# Reason to connect UIPickerView datasource and delegate in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am new in IOS development and  I am working with UIPickerView. I am reading a book named:

> Beginning iPhone Development with Swift

At page 222 that book told to do this:

> Next, with the picker selected, press ⌥z6 to bring up the Connections Inspector. If you look at the connections available for the picker view, you’ll see that the first two items are dataSource and delegate. If you don’t see those outlets, make sure you have the picker selected, rather than the UIView that contains it! Drag from the circle next to dataSource to the View Controller icon. at the top of the scene in the storyboard or in the Document Outline, and then drag from the circle next to delegate to the View Controller icon.

But i don't know the reason of this connection. Please can can you explain it. Thanks.

Comment: You are telling that the datasource and delegate methods of picker is implemented in that view controller. You can also do that in code by setting `picker.datasource = viewcntrollerObj;` and `picker.delegate = viewcntrollerObj;`

Comment: What is the reason to do that?

Comment: Delegate and datasource must be connected as to set values in picker as well as getting element from it. in short you must have to set delegate and datasource

Comment: Try running without the connection, you will see nothing on picker. To fill the data in the picker you need data source. And to get the events from the picker you need delegate

Comment: But how connection is helping here? @InderKumarRathore

Comment: If you are asking for the advantage, 1) You don't need to declare any IBOutlet connection for picker, particularly for specifying delegate and datasource. 2) You don't need to set datasource and delegate by code.

Comment: What happen when connect with storyboard. Actually i want to know the mechanism

Comment: [Delegation and Datasource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)

Answer (score 2):

Delegate Protocol

The delegate must adopt the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol and implement the required methods to return the drawing rectangle for rows in each component. It also provides the content for each component’s row, either as a string or a view, and it typically responds to new selections or deselections.

Datasource Protocol

The data source must adopt the UIPickerViewDataSource protocol and implement the required methods to return the number of components and the number of rows in each component.

Check this link
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPickerView/dataSource